# How to re-enable PrintScreen shortcut to fire ksnapshot?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde, system-settings, ksnapshot

In the past I used to fire `ksnapshot` by hitting the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key on my keyboard.

Since some time now (< 1 year, I am running Kubuntu 14.04 with KDE v4.13.3) this is not happening anymore.

Moreover, in *System Settings → Shortcuts and Gestures → Global keyboard shortcuts* there seems to be no way to setup in `kwin ksnapshot` with the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key.

Any solution? Is this a bug?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+bug/1243733

Comment: The path is KDE System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures > Custom Shortcuts. And there the Preset Actions > PrintScreen Trigger&Action tabs. Trigger shortcut:Print, action command:ksnapshot. Is this set ?

Comment: Yes, it's there. No, it is disabled. I enabled it and it worked. I have not been the one to disable it, for sure. So I'd say the cange has been triggered by some update. Thanks.

Comment: @Helio. That's sounds like the usual stuff with bugs at launchpad. Either none is paying attention or the ones who do don't investigate enough. Thanks for the link, though.